# How to use an <MSBuild..> task with regard to incremental build?

Tags: msbuild, target

My project B in one configuration depends on outputs of project A in different configurations. Thus I use something like this in project B:

```
<Project
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      BatchDeps;
      $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BatchDeps">
     <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionPath)" Targets="A" Properties="Configuration=Config1" SkipNonexistentTargets="True"/>
     <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionPath)" Targets="A" Properties="Configuration=Config2" SkipNonexistentTargets="True"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now I would like to support incremental build so that when sources of the project A change then B actually builds instead of reporting "All outputs are up-to-date".
How to achieve this behavior ?

Comment: You need to specify inputs and outputs of target. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019)

Comment: That's quite the question, how can I grab the inputs from the MSBuild task automatically ?